# What is "node-waf" and how to get it on Windows?

Tags: node.js

What is "node-waf" for node.js and how do I get it on a Windows development machine?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

node-waf is a wrapper around the build system [waf](http://code.google.com/p/waf/) to simplify building of native C++ extensions for node.js. As far as I know there's not yet a replacement for windows.

But I know that some people managed to build native extensions with Vistual Studio instead.

[This repository](https://github.com/Benvie/contextify) contains a windows build for [contextify](http://search.npmjs.org/#/contextify), needed for [jsdom](http://search.npmjs.org/#/jsdom). Maybe you can look at how it is built and adapt that.

Comment: Yes, I've used built contextify to install jsdom. But I need bcrypt (for mongoose-auth) but after some hours (using instructions http://botsikas.blogspot.com/2011/12/building-native-modules-for-nodejs-06.html) I couldn't get it compiled with VS  =(

Comment: For those new to node coming across this. node-gyp has replaced node-waf. If you need to build with node-waf look for a more up to date version of the module or convert it to node-gyp yourself.

Comment: @jholloman - What do you think are the chances that "those new to node" will know how to go about converting to node-gyp? I know google is your friend, but really...

Comment: any guides on converting to node-gyp for those of us new with modules that are out of date?