# persistence.js on nodejs on windows box

Tags: windows, node.js, persistence

Hitting a problem with my node.js server on windows when installing persistence.js.

Getting errors starting with : 'node-waf' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Found this:
node-waf is a wrapper around the build system waf to simply building of native C++ extensions for node.js. As far as I know there's not yet a replacement for windows.

Is there any way to get persistence.js up and running on my set up?

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install git://github.com/zefhemel/persistencejs.git
```

`node-waf` is required to install an `sqlite` dependency. However looking at the `package.json` on the git repo, this was removed. You are safe if you install directly from the git repo.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this persistence.js is dependent on 'node-waf':

**Summary of node-waf:**
"node-waf is a wrapper around the build system waf to simply building of native C++ extensions for node.js."

**Post with potential same problem:**
Read this, it may be of some help:
[What is "node-waf" and how to get it on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465248/node-js-what-is-node-waf-and-how-to-get-it-on-windows)

### Problem Resolution:

Blog post relating the matter on Nodejs.org:
http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/01/23/node-v0-7-1/