# Is there any node-waf for Node.js on windows?

Tags: windows, node.js, npm, waf

I am trying to install the 'png' module from Node.js using the following command:

npm install png

however I am getting the following error:

> node-waf configure build

'node-waf' is not recognized as an internal or external command

My question is: Is there node-waf for windows?

Comment: See the thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465248/node-js-what-is-node-waf-and-how-to-get-it-on-windows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Node 0.8, the waf build system has been **removed** and replaced with the cross-platform [node-gyp](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp).

To get gyp running on Windows, you need [Python 2.7](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.3#download) and [MS Visual C++](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express) (and for x64 builds, the [Win 7 x64 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displayLang=en&id=8279)).

Of course, having gyp doesn't help you install the particular package you want (since it uses waf).  Normally, you'd have to get the project's maintainer to upgrade to the new build system, or fork it and fix it yourself (it's not [that hard](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp#the-bindinggyp-file)).

However, it looks like the author of node-png in fact has added gyp bindings in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/pkrumins/node-png), but hasn't pushed those changes to npm (perhaps they don't work yet).  You could try cloning the repo and seeing if you can get it to build.